# Dynamically change renderer.text css attribute in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I want to dynamically change the css attribute color value on my gauge chart.
The function to display text is here:

```
function setText(text, x, check) {
    var chart = $('#graph-4').highcharts();

    if ( check === true ) {
        var color = '#ffffff';
    } else {
        var color = '#555555';
    }

    var ret = chart.renderer.text(text, chart.plotWidth*x, chart.plotHeight*0.5)
    .attr({
        zIndex: 5
    })
    .css({
        fontSize: '13px',
        color: color,
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
    })
    .add();
}
```

Before my my code is calling to function setText, it's checking the incoming value from JSON, so if the incoming value is less than 0 (zero), then my text should be displayed with one color and when the incoming value is bigger than 0 (zero) the text should be displayed with another color.
The chart is dynamically refreshing values going from JSON and series is updated by command:

```
chart.series[0].setData(incoming_value);
```

After this line, when I'm calling the function:

```
setText('myText', 0.3, colorParameter);
```

Each refresh generate new text added on top of last text so it's generate new lines in code and not clean visual effects.

How I can update this css property dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your function so on the first call it creates a label and then, when the label is already created, changes some params only.

```
function setText(text, x, check) {
  var chart = $('#graph-4').highcharts();
  var ret = this.customText;
  console.log(chart);
  if (check === true) {
    var color = '#ffffff';
  } else {
    var color = '#555555';
  }

  if (!ret) {
    ret = this.customText = chart.renderer.text(null, -9999, -9999)
    .attr({
      zIndex: 5
    })
    .css({
      fontSize: '13px',
      'text-anchor': 'middle'
    })
    .add();
  }

  ret.attr({
    text: text,
    x: chart.plotWidth * x,
    y: chart.plotHeight * 0.5
  }).css({
    color: color
  });
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/qdnk21ej/

Comment: This is useful if I want to display only one label. But if I want to display two (or more) labels using 'setText' function it work only for the last occurence in code. So what we can change in your's code to make it more universal/repeatable? Temporary I've created a second function 'setText2' and changed 'this.customText' to 'this.customText1'.

Comment: I would create an array/object which keeps all the custom texts and add another param to the function which identify the text to be changed - http://jsfiddle.net/qdnk21ej/1/